# why android:textDirection="locale" not work on EditText's hint password on Arabic?

Tags: android

xml layout:

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Email Address"
                android:textColor="@color/common_text_color_1"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_common_size_1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/common_line_color_edit_text"
                android:hint="Tab to enter email"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textDirection="locale"

                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_common_size_1" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/underline_distance_from_input_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/common_edit_text_underline_button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/distance_between_input_fields"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="@color/common_text_color_1"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_common_size_1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/common_line_color_edit_text"
                android:hint="Tab to enter password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textDirection="locale"

                android:textSize="@dimen/input_text_common_size_1" />
```

and here result:

[image]

To correct align I use `android:textDirection="locale"`

It's work just fine.

When I select Arabic, then whole text is success alignment. Nice.
But password hint not. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`android:textAlignment="viewStart"`

Add the above line to your `EditText` in `.xml` file.